# Cannot get data from my Dropbox Datastore using the Dropbox Datastore API

Tags: ios, mobile, synchronization, dropbox, datastore

When I use the Dropbox Datastore API and link to another iOS device, I am not able to get the data in my datastore, but I can get the data in the datastore by using the first iOS device that I set up to use the Datastore API.  What could be the problem here?

The code is of course the same that is being run on both devices.

```
DBAccount * account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];
DBDatastore *dataStore = [DBDatastore openDefaultStoreForAccount:account error:nil];
DBTable *table = [dataStore getTable:@"crane"];

__pastCranes = [InspectionBussiness getRecords:nil DBAccount:account DBDatastore:dataStore DBTable:table];
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Do you have multiple Dropbox accounts? (Maybe you're linking different accounts on the two devices.)

Comment: Just checked, only using the one account...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I figured it out.  Somewhere after you link the Dropbox Account to this device you have to add this line.  For me it was:

```
[dataStore sync:nil];
```

This updated the datastore on my device.  Then I could load the cranes.

It's strange though, because it doesn't work immediately.  I had to run the app a few times before the updated information appeared in the table view.

Comment: Well, you should be calling `sync` every time there's a change. You should have an observer set up on the datastore, and if the `DBDatastoreIncoming` flag is true, you should call `sync`. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/ios#listeners. If you never call `sync`, you'll never see the new data from the server.

Comment: please help me @smarx ..Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347592/unable-to-get-data-from-dropbox-in-ios

Comment: Hey Iam facing the same problem.Please help me @adeji

Comment: What exactly is your issue?  The data is just not appearing on another device? @Jack1231