# Unable to get data from Dropbox in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on IOS application.Integrated Dropbox successfully and saving data as record in datastores in DropBox as well.It was fine till here.But I am unable to get data after deleting application and reinstalling it.But in one scenario I am getting data i.e,"I inserted a record in any one of the tables in datastores,after inserting that when I am trying to get data Its coming successfully".But I need to get for the first time as the app installs.If any one worked on it  please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)dropBoxScuccessLogin:(NSString *)successString
{
if ([successString isEqualToString:@"scuccess"])
{
       //appdelegate.window.rootViewController = appdelegate.splitview;


    NSArray *array1=[appdelegate.datastoreManager listDatastores:nil];
    NSLog(@"array is %@",array1);

    if (self.account)
    {
        NSDate *mydate=[NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM-DD-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
        NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:mydate];

        DBTable  *customerTbl = [self.store getTable:@"DataSyncedOndate"];
        DBRecord *task = [customerTbl insert:@{ @"SyncedDate": stringFromDate} ];
        __weak DropBoxViewController *slf = self;
        [self.store addObserver:self block:^ {
            if (slf.store.status & (DBDatastoreIncoming | DBDatastoreOutgoing))
            {
                [self syncTasks];
            }
        }];
        [self.store sync:nil];

    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Dropbox Login faild");
}

}

- (void)syncTasks
{
NSLog(@"Self Account is in syncTasks is %@",self.account);
if (self.account)
{
     NSDictionary *changed = [self.store sync:nil];
    NSLog(@" Data is Synced");
    // [self getDataSync];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self retriveDataFromDB];
    });
    // [self performSelector:@selector(getDataSync) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
else
{
    // [alertView show];
}
```

}

in retriveDataFromDB method

```
-(void)retriveDataFromDB
{

NSLog(@"retrive from DB method called");

///////////Admin details///////////
NSMutableArray *tasks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self.store getTable:@"PriceList"] query:nil error:nil]];

NSLog(@"tasks count is %d",[tasks count]);
for (int k=0; k<[tasks count]; k++)
{
    DBRecord *recordObj=[tasks objectAtIndex:k];
    NSString  *Tier1_Id =recordObj[@"Tier1"];
    NSString  *Tier2_Id =recordObj[@"Tier2"];
    NSString  *Tier3_Id =recordObj[@"Tier3"];
    NSString  *Code_Id =recordObj[@"Code"];
    NSString  *CRV_Id =recordObj[@"CRV"];

    NSString *insertAdminString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO admin_Tbl(Code,Tier1,Tier2,Tier3,CRV) VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",Code_Id,Tier1_Id,Tier2_Id,Tier3_Id,CRV_Id];

    BOOL isDataadded = [appdelegate executeInsertQuery:insertAdminString];
    if (isDataadded == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"admin table insertrd successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"admin table not insertrd successfully");
    }
}

}
```

In Log I am getting tasks count is "0".

Comment: @smarx  will you please guide me

Comment: Do you have an observer set up on the datastore? Are you calling `sync` in there when there are incoming changes? See the tutorial: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/ios#listeners. If that's not it, please post some code.

Comment: @smarx please go through my edited question with some code

Comment: It looks like you're never calling `sync`. At least, neither `syncTasks` nor `retriveDataFromDB` in the code you shared actually call `sync`. (I see a commented out line that used to do it, though. So I guess you tried it at one point?)